# Newbie xubuntu with kde no wireless

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, kde, 14.04

Newbie (to here) help requested. I currently run xubuntu (just upgraded to 14.04) and have no issues. Thought I would try kde, just for a change. Running on a laptop with enough grunt for that, I just like the xfce environment. I installed kde with:

`sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`

This worked ok. I logged in and the look and feel are different but may be worth moving to. However, some basic functions are missing, like being able to enable wireless and log onto a wireless network. No icon for wireless, no settings in any of the control panels, no response to `KNetworkManager` (could not be found with an apt-cache search `KNetworkManager` either. I tried to install wicd but this would not initialise and failed each login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest you try kubuntu with the live USB.

If you like that, then install kubuntu-desktop ;

```
sudo apt-get install -y kubuntu-desktop
```

The desktop meta package will install the missing parts / functionality.

Comment: Thanks, do you recommend uninstalling kde-plasma first?

Comment: not unless you only want part of kde / kubuntu desktop and you know what packages you do and do not want.

Comment: Thanks, reading back I asked a dumb thing, sorry. I will try it, thank you for the help

Comment: is OK, you are learning.